# two subnets on the same interface one with dhcp

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

Can I create a network alias when the interface is currently using dhcp?

I'm trying to make 10.99.77.0/24 assignable on my network and routable to/from 192.168.1.0/24. Is there a better alternative to this approach?

```
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto enp4s0:1
iface enp4s0:1 inet static
    address 10.99.77.1
    network 10.99.77.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.99.77.255
```

Comment: What distro are you trying to do this on?

Comment: That is the proper configuration to get Debian (or Debian based - Ubuntu, Mint, etc) to have 2 subnets on one interface.  Unfortunately, if you are going to NAT the 10.99.77.0/24 network, `iptables` doesn't understand aliased ethernet device names... And I think that just plain packet forwarding might also need non-aliased device name(s) too...

Comment: Ubuntu. The network will not come up with these settings. 

Cannot find device "enp4s0:1"
Failed to bring up enp4s0:1.

Comment: That style of interface alias is long deprecated and parts of the system do not recognize it anymore (if they ever did).